# UI Design to explain translation and rotation of an specific object to the reference

Tags: user-expectation, usability-testing, placement

I want to explain and show the user in which way he should rotate or move the object to fit exactly in the right place. The user can't see the orientation points that are outside the view. He also doesn't know in which angle or position the object should be placed in the view.

I had a few discussions about this solution with the crosses. So if you have some ideas or just feedback to my solution it would be great!

[image: blub]

In this picture I just want to describe the problem and all three ways to move the object, that are moving it along the x-axis, the y-axis or simply rotate it.

[image: blub]

This picture shows my solution for this problem so far. The user must bring the red cross exactly on the black cross. The black cross is the place we want to reach, if the red cross turns into green the object is in the right position.

Comment: As a coworker I can clarify some things: The object is a real physical one (max. 3*3cm) in front of the user and he/she needs to position it correctly. For this purpose a camera is used. The user will see a live stream of the object and we already have the detection of the current position implemented. The UI shall help the user to place it in the right position as fast and easy as possible. Don't know if I should edit the question, because I am not the author.

Answer (score 2):

This is a tough one but I think you can bear the same effect / guidance a tad more discreetly.

Firstly I would indicate that the object can be manipulated in all directions with an icon that is easily recognisable.

Then I would have a point in the center of the rectangle that changes appearance depending on how close the user is to bringing the object to the right direction. Similar to your cross there, but a bit more discreet without occupying too much space.

See screenshots attached.

[image]
[image]

I am approaching this with the logic that you want your users to figure out the right alignment themselves. Without too obvious signs or guidance.

Now, I might be waaaay off to what you have in mind. I do not know the purpose of the app and I do not know the potential users. These are key questions that will affect your implementation.

Do you want the users to figure the alignment out themselves?
Do you want to spell it out for them on how centered the rectangle needs to be?
Are your users of an age (or tech familiarity) where this concept will not be completely new?

I have no idea and there is no 100% right way to do this. UX in 3D through a 2D medium is tough and it will take some trial and error. Hell, it feels difficult for me to convey my idea to you and we both "speak" the same language here.

I suggest you try out different methods and test with some users. See what's more intuitive for them and of course, consider your goals as well.

Comment: As a coworker I can clarify some things: The object is a real physical one (max. 3*3cm) in front of the user and he/she needs to position it correctly. For this purpose a camera is used. The user will see a live stream of the object and we already have the detection and highlightning of it implemented. The UI shall help the user to place it in the right position as fast and easy as possible. Thank you for your help!

Comment: Ah that changes things. You have a very specific scenario. Have you by any chance tested with your users to find what troubles them in your original mockup? I feel that user testing is going to be the surefire way to solve this due to the nature of this problem.

Comment: Not yet. At the moment they want 3 different status bars for x, y and the rotation but we think that the solution with the plus would improve the speed because you only have one piece of informations to look for. Now want arguments for or against those options. Or a completely different approach, we are open for everything.